# How to download a public shared file from Onedrive throught NIFI using Onedrive API

Tags: apache-nifi, onedrive

I am trying to dowload files from this [websit](https://worldhealthorg-my.sharepoint.com/personal/karamg_who_int/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?originalPath=aHR0cHM6Ly93b3JsZGhlYWx0aG9yZy1teS5zaGFyZXBvaW50LmNvbS86ZjovZy9wZXJzb25hbC9rYXJhbWdfd2hvX2ludC9FZzhGbTJQNUg3bENuSmpEWmFWTFhjUUItRmJaQ2o0RUIwX2JQOUdsZFlEQTBRP3J0aW1lPTFLZWI5Zm14MkVn&sortField=Modified&isAscending=true&id=%2Fpersonal%2Fkaramg%5Fwho%5Fint%2FDocuments%2FICTRP%20weekly%20updates) using One drive API in invokeHttp.

So I append suffix like this /me/drive/items/ICTRPFullExport-672212-23-11-20/content

However, I cannot download the file.

I put this website into the postman, it show 403 error. But I also configure the username and password in the invokeHttp.

How can I fix this?

Comment: 403 means forbidden - have you tried trying to download the file outside of NiFi via API e.g. via the browser or a curl using the same creds & url?

Comment: @Sdairs yes, i can download it via the browser with the same URL. But when I can not send the same request to nifi.

Comment: How are you configuring auth in InvokeHTTP? Using Basic Auth? Have you tried a curl from cli using Basic Auth creds to see if basic auth is allowed?

Comment: I just set the URL and username and password. Could you please have a try with that website?